# Why does Git seem not to exist when I run VS Code as an Administrator?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Windows machine, trying to clone a repo down. I am using the Terminal in VS Code.

When I first tried to clone the repo I was met with permissions issues. A Google of the problem suggested I run VS Code as Administrator.

However, when I attempted clone the repo again I was met with the error:

`The term 'git' is not recognize as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

When I run `git -v` I get the same message.

However, opening VS Code normally, not as Administrator, as running `git -v` produces the correct and expected result.

Why is it Git is not recognised when use VS Code as an Administrator?

Comment: What about if you open a regular command prompt or other command line tool as an admin and try?

Comment: @TimothyG. I tried that too and got the same results. Its odd - I can have 2 command line consoles open side by side, one run as Admin, and the Admin one still wont recognize Git

Comment: That at least means it must not be a VS Code thing. I'm not really sure how this could happen though. Is the git.exe in your Environment variable PATH? Or only your user path?

Comment: If it doesn't work in other consoles it sounds like the path to git.exe isn't part of your operating system path variables.